# Laravel 5.8: dynamic table name of the model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.8.

I need to set the table of a model dynamically when I define the relation in another model.

The model \App\ProductAttribute can have different table name and I would like to define dynamically from the Product model.

I have tried something (view comments) but it didn't work.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\ProductAttribute;

class Product extends Model
{

    public function attributes(){

        $table = $this->attribute_set->attribute_set_table;

        // I've tried that but it doesn't work
        // $instance = new ProductAttribute::class;
        // $instance->setTable($table);
        // return $this->hasOne( $instance );

        // I've also tried that but it doesn't work
        // return $this->hasOne( ProductAttribute::class )->with(['table' => $table]);

        return $this->hasOne( ProductAttribute::class );
    }
}
```

Comment: Test this. Define `protected $table;` then use a constructor like this: `public function __construct ($tableName) { $this->table = $tableName; }`

Comment: Could you maybe hardcode the possible attributes? `public function attributes1()` `public function attributes2()` ...